# CSS Highlight Table Row But Not When Hovering First 3 Cells

Tags: html, css

I would like to highlight a row (change the background color) when i hover over any cell excluding the first 3 cells on the row (button cells). I also need to exclude the first row from the grid as that is the header row. (Images show desired behavior)

I have tried using many different :hover css selectors. But i cant seem to find the combination that allows me to highlight the row when hovering over any cell **except** the first 3.

```
table tr:hover td {
  background-color: #e6e600;
}

<table>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Gender</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><button></button></td>
  <td><button></button></td>
  <td><button></button></td>
  <th>Joe</th>
  <th>37</th>
  <th>Male</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: "*I would like to highlight a row (change the background color) when i hover over any cell excluding the first 3 cells on the row (button cells)*" - so, all cells except the first three should have a highlight, or hovering on any cell except the first three should highlight the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4<sup>th</sup>, 5th<sup>th</sup>, and 6<sup>th</sup>
columns were all `<th>`, the cells that are in the `<tbody>` should be `<td>`, so that is corrected. Also, I added a `<thead>` to it as well and an extra `<tr>` to show that the highlight affects each `<tr>` separately.

In order to meet the following criteria:

- no JavaScript
- ***valid*** HTML and CSS only
- the 4<sup>th</sup>, 5th<sup>th</sup>, and 6<sup>th</sup> `<td>` of any `<tr>` within the `<tbody>` should all be highlighted at once if any one of them is hovered over.
- the 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>, and 3<sup>rd</sup> `<td>` of any `<tr>` within the `<tbody>` should never trigger any effects when hovering over them.

A sub-table could be used to isolate the last 3 columns:

- in the `<tbody>`, remove the last 2 `<td>` of each `<tr>`.
- add `colspan="3"` to the last `<td>` of each `<tr>` within the `<tbody>`
- add a `<table>` into each of those `<td colspan="3">`
- add a `<tr>` into that `<table>`
- add 3 `<td>` into that `<tr>`

**Figure I** - a sub-table

```html
      <td class='col' colspan='3'>
        <table class='sub'>
          <tr><td>Joe</td><td>37</td><td>Male</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  width: 5%;
}

th:nth-of-type(4) {
  width: 50%;
}

th:nth-of-type(5) {
  width: 5%;
}

th:nth-of-type(6) {
  width: 15%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  text-align:center;
}

.col {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  outline-offset: 0;
}

.sub tr:hover td {
  background: #fc0;
}

.sub {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0.5px solid #000;
}

.sub td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid 0.5px;
  text-align: left;
}

.sub td:first-of-type {
  width: 70%;
  border-left: 0;
}

.sub td:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub td:last-of-type {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button>A</button></td>
      <td><button>B</button></td>
      <td><button>C</button></td>
      <td class='col' colspan='3'>
        <table class='sub'>
          <tr><td>Joe</td><td>37</td><td>Male</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button>A</button></td>
      <td><button>B</button></td>
      <td><button>C</button></td>
      <td class='col' colspan='3'>
        <table class='sub'>
          <tr><td>Jill</td><td>37</td><td>Female</td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Will this highlight the whole row if i hover only one td? By the looks of the code only one td will get highlighted right? Thanks

Comment: No, hover over anywhere over `<tr>` and the 4th, 5th, and 6th `<td>` of that `<tr>` is highlighted.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what im looking for, If i hover over the first three, i don't want anything to be highlighted. Thanks though.

Comment: That slight change in color when you hover over the buttons is a browser default. That can be easily changed. Or do you mean the 1st row in it's entirety? Which can be easily changed as well.

Comment: @Funnythat updated answer.

Comment: Having a sub table sounds like a great idea, thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully possible without JS as CSS has no parent selector. A few browsers (Safari and Chrome Desktop) already included the `:has()`-selector but as said, it is not fully supported yet.

The closest thing you an do without scripting is to highlight all `th` in a `row`. That said, you can use the `tr:hover` selector to check for a hover on the entire row. This means the hover will also trigger if you hover the first 3 elements. The background-highlighting therefore will only be used on the `th`. To exclude the first row you can use the `:not()`-selector:

```css
table tr:not(:nth-child(1)):hover th {
  background-color: #e6e600;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Gender</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><button></button></td>
  <td><button></button></td>
  <td><button></button></td>
  <th>Joe</th>
  <th>37</th>
  <th>Male</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have a solution that includes scripting?